# Using strings in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I need a way for a users input to be used in an `if` statement:

```
print("Hello, World!")

name = input("What is your name?")

hobby = input("Cool, so " + name + " what do you do you for fun? You can say something like play, work, learn, etc.")

play = 'play'
work = 'work'
learn = 'learn'

if hobby = play
    print('awesome')

elif hobby = work
    print('must be busy')

elif hobby =  learn
    print('ha, me too')
```

Comment: The comparison operator is `==` not `=`

Answer (score 6):

The `if`, `elif` and `else` statements must be terminated by a `:`. Also `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment. So

```
if hobby == play:
    print('awesome')

elif hobby == work:
    print('must be busy')

elif hobby == learn:
    print('ha, me too')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you are missing `:` and `==` operator, but in your case instead of else-if ladders, you can use a dictionary.

```
from __future__ import print_function

actions = {'play': 'awesome', 'work': 'must be busy', 'learn': 'ha, me too', }

if hobby in actions:
   print(actions[hobby])
else:
   print("default case")
```

OR

```
from __future__ import print_function

actions = {'play': 'awesome', 'work': 'must be busy', 'learn': 'ha, me too', }

try:
   print(actions[hobby])
except KeyError:
   print("default case")
```

Comment: @AJSloniewsky which version you are using? comment the error you got !

Comment: Oh never mind I just forgot to put [from __future__ import print_function] at the beginning of the script

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the assignment by coding

```
if hobby == 'play':
    print('awesome')
```

OR

```
if hobby == play:
    print('awesome')
```

Comment: Please format your code using SO's built in code beautifier.